# USB-C Strange voltage bias detected on shield and unconnected pins interfering with signal

Tags: usb-c

I'm having trouble figuring out why there is a 1.8 V bias on the shield and the unconnected pins of my USB-C connector.

Some background... I am attempting to use USB-C connectors to connect two ICs together across two boards and also pipe the USB data from a PC to the second IC. So the configuration looks like this:
[image: USB configuration]

So the regular USB lines (GND,+,-,VUSB) are adapted, so to speak, through the USB-C connectors. I've tried to use the extra pins on the USB-C connectors for the data, clock and reset lines required to connect the two ICs across the two boards.

It seemed like a good idea since I need a user friendly way to connect the two boards and USB-C provides plenty of unused pins that I could repurpose. So far nothing is working as it should. I see a mysterious 1.8V bias on all the unconnected pins of the connector as well as the shield which seems to also be interfering with my signal. It shows up on the data line, but not the clock which is odd. Here is a capture showing the bias:
[image]

Is there something fundamentally wrong with using the USB-C connectors in this way? I want to provide a common connector so that the second board can be charged conveniently as it is a battery powered device. The first board is a programmer for the device and it requires 3 pins to do its job. This seemed like an ideal solution until I found out what a challenge USB-C can be.

I would really appreciate any guidance from folks who have experience working with USB-C and who can tell me what I am doing wrong. Is there any way to make this work? Thanks so much!

Comment: Type-C is just a connector, it can't bias anything. Double check all other electronics that you have crafted. Cables, however, might have some active components, but only on CC1/CC2 lines.

Comment: The really odd thing is that the bias is 1.8 V, like it is being caused by something acting like a divider somewhere. It it were shorted to the high side, it would be 3.3 or 5 V, and if it were shorted to ground it would be 0 V. If it were truly floating I would see the characteristic 60 Hz noise from the probe pickup. It's def a 1.8 VDC signal... but from where? I tested the continuity of the pins and nothing appears to be shorted at least as far as I can tell.